# Detecting abrupt changes in fuel tank

Tags: signal-analysis

We are trying to find loading and unloading patterns for time series created by tank fuel measurements.

Our data after a low pass filter to cancel the noise are shown in the plot below:

[image]

We are trying to securely find the fuel loadings that happen periodically and the value of the loading, i.e. 110 liters for example.

Is there a state of the art algorithm to approach this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That seems straight forward enough. You know that the ONLY event that can increase fuel levels is fueling and other than that, the tank level should be monastically decreasing at a relatively constant rate.

Here is what I would do

1. Do NOT low-pass filter. That's just going to smear out your transients
2. Identify the "fueling" event by looking for a positive jump (first derivative) above a certain threshold. The threshold can be determined by looking at the "noise level" or your raw data.
3. Determine the amount of fuel by averaging a few readings before and after the jump and taking the difference. How much averaging you need depends again on the amount of noise in your readings.